# EditText with default value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) with an .input-group-addon to prepend or append elements to a single form element like the TextArea input type of form.
Prepend simple means it shows it contains value disabled from editing by a user.

How can I do this in my andriod app? It is with my XML or what?
Please help...

Comment: try using android:text property in layout xml file

Comment: can you please explain with some example what you want to achieve..??

Comment: @pmcs management post some code

Comment: So you want to add a list of predefined values to a textbox(Edittext) which should not be edited by the user right?

Comment: If you want to display simple predefined text then you may try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft simple drawables.

Answer (score 5):

I think following code will help you to do so.

**Solution 1**

`TextView` will show only prefix text, and `EditText` can be of user's choice.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="www.google.com"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In above layout, you will see `TextView` having your default text, but user is only able to write in `EditText`. So user will not have any idea about such trick.

**Solution 2**

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.setText("http://");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());


edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!s.toString().contains("http://")){
            edt.setText("http://");
            Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());
        }
    }
});
```

This solution will not allow user to remove "http://" from its `EditText` input.

Answer (score 3):

`EditText` extends `TextView` which extend `View` class. And `View.java` class has method `setText` which pretty much works for every view which extends `View.java`.

**Conclustion**

```
EditText.setText("your Text here"); //set default value

EditText.setHint("your Text here"); //set hint
```

**In Xml**

```
 android:text="@string/yourStringText"
```